# WPF - Property not binded using DataType

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a main viewmodel with several child viewmodel

For each childVM, I have definied the following in the main view:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <vm:MainVM x:Key="MainVM" />

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ChildVM}">
        <view:childview />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Inside childview there's a textbox with:

```
<TextBox>
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behavior:AppendTextBehavior AppendTextAction="{Binding AppendTextAction, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

The behavior class:

```
public class AppendTextBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
{
    public Action<string> AppendTextAction
    {
        get { return (Action<string>)GetValue(AppendTextActionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AppendTextActionProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AppendTextActionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AppendTextAction", typeof(Action<string>), typeof(AppendTextBehavior));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        SetCurrentValue(AppendTextActionProperty, (Action<string>)AssociatedObject.AppendText);
        AssociatedObject.TextChanged += AssociatedObject_TextChanged;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // does something
    }
}
```

Main view

```
<TabControl
    ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs, Mode=OneWay}"
    >
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        </StackPanel>
        ..
        <Button Content="+" Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource MainVM}, Path=AddTabCommand}" />

    </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
<TabControl>
```

Main ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<ChildVM> tabs;

public ObservableCollection<ChildVM> Tabs
{
    get
    {
        return tabs;
    }
    set
    {
        tabs = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => Tabs);
    }
}

void AddTab()
{
    ChildVM tab = new ChildVM();
    Tabs.Add(tab);                 
}

public ICommand AddTabCommand { get { return new MvvmFoundation.Wpf.RelayCommand(AddTab); } }
```

Finally, ChildVM has:

```
private Action<string> appendTextAction;

public Action<string> AppendTextAction
{
    get { return appendTextAction; }
    set {
        appendTextAction = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => AppendTextAction);
    }
}
```

Now, AppendTextAction's VM is always null, so the binding doesn't work.

BUT, if I try to create the childVM within the view like this:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:ChildVM>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

The Binding works perfectly!

Obviously the code above is wrong, because I don't need to create the child view model again

What can I do to make the AppendTextAction binding work ?

Comment: <view:childview DataContext="{Binding}"/> ?

Comment: Yes, ChildVM and childVM are the same class

Comment: How is the DataTemplate being applied, i.e. how does your ItemsControls look like and how and where do you bind its ItemsSource property and to what?

Comment: @mm8 See the update (Main view and Main ViewModel)

Comment: It is still as unclear where the DataTemplate that contains the childview is being applied...you have a TabControl with some other DataTemplate?

Comment: See the first part, where on the main view I have definied a dataTemplate.
Also, I corrected Tabs with the right name (ChildVM)

Comment: @FabrizioStellato why there is some other DataTemplate has been set as content of TabControl?

Comment: One is for the tabitem header, while the <view:childview /> is for the tabitem content